# which is more effective chilling for metal casting, thick copper die or water-cooled thin copper mold?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, thermal-conductivity, cooling

It is will known that increasing cooling of a metal casting will lead to finer micro-structure which mean higher mechanical properties.
If I have 2 molds one is thick copper die ,& second is just thin-walled copper cup or mold cooled by water. which one of them excepted to cool the molten metal i.e. aluminium faster ?

by calculation it seems that copper die have higher cooling power as it has higher thermal diffusivity , but in real life it seems water have more cooling power. I am so confused.

Comment: You'd have to show us your calculation. For instance, did it consider the water convection (or even forced flow)?

Answer (score 1):

The thick copper will quickly draw heat away from the casting because of its high conductivity. But unless you actively cool the other end it will quickly heat up to the same temperature as the metal because Copper has a low heat capacity.

Water has a lower thermal conductivity, so only water near the metal surface will heat quickly. But water has a high capacity and so can absorb a lot of energy as it warms up. More importantly you can constantly flow new cold water past the die taking the energy away with the warmed water.

IMPORTANT - this is the answer for a homework question. If you want to see what happens when water gets near molten metal, search youtube for "explosions from metal casting"